# Unit test check-in policy tfs 2012

Tags: unit-testing, policy, checkin

Is there a way to add a check-in policy to enforce that unit tests are run and pass before checking-in files ?

On the following page MS mentions Testing Policy but I don't see it in the policies dialog box and don't find how to add it, any idea ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264876.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2012/10/15/available-check-in-policies-for-team-foundation-server-2012/) the policy is not longer available in TFS2012.

> Note: The Testing Policy that shipped with VS 2010 is not longer available.

I haven't found a solution yet.